# Separate click and mouseover maker listeners for google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have set up my makers to dynamically call up an info window AND redirect through to a URL on mouseover thus:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);  
      location.href='/places/'+locations[i][3];
    }
  })(marker, i));
```

How would i modify this so that the info window part happens on mouseover, but the location.href part only happens on click? I've been playing with some permutations and i cant get it to work.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**
I found the answer: i think i'd missed a semicolon or something:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i)); 

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {     
      location.href='/spots/'+locations[i][3];
    }
  })(marker, i));
```

Comment: Redirect on mouse over? That is so annoying that it would cause me to blacklist and block your site.

Comment: thanks for that. that's exactly what i was trying to fix. read the question dude.